# Which UTM system do you recommend for Tamaulipas, Mexico?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm working with QGIS 1.8.0. Could anyone tell me which UTM system would be better to project a map of Mexico? There are too many to choose from. I have to convert my maps from WGS84 to UTM to do some distance measurements.

Please let me know. 
Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jens answered, UTM zone 14 North is the best zone for Tamaulipas.

If I remember correctly, Mexico provided information for the original NAD83 definition, but never officially published/converted to NAD83. [INEGI](http://www.inegi.org.mx/) did release a Red Geodesica Nacional 1993 datum (also known in the [EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org) as Mexican Datum of 1993). The EPSG ID is 4487. EPSG has a null transformation (parameters are zeroes) only for Mexican Datum of 1993 to WGS84.

NAD83 (CSRS) should not be used because, as Jens pointed out, it's for Canada. NAD83 (CSRS) is a re-adjustment of the original NAD83, but for Canada only. Other re-adjustments include several for the US: NAD83 HARN, NAD83 (NSRS2007), and NAD83 (2011).

Even though the PROJ.4 definitions are the same, as Andre Joost said, an incorrect definition will cause confusion in the future, and make it more difficult to convert data to a different coordinate reference system, if necessary.

For 
Note: I'm on the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG registry.

Answer (score 2):

Mexico (the country, not the city) covers 6 UTM zones: from *WGS 84 / UTM zone 11N* in the west to *WGS 84 / UTM zone 16N* in the east. It does not make sense to use *one* UTM zone for entire country. In [this image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Utm-zones.jpg) you can see the UTM zones.

For the state Tamaulipas in the Northeast of Mexico *zone 14* fit best.  Therefore these systems (amongst others) can be used in Tamaulipas:

- NAD 83 / UTM zone 14N
- WGS 84 / UTM zone 14N

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jens. So its the same if I choose the systems NAD83CSRS/UTMzone 14N, NAD83/UTMzone14N or NAD27/UTMzone 14N?

Comment: I meant for a state in Northeast (Tamaulipas) Mexico. Which one would you recommend?

Comment: NAD27 is outdated, the others should be the same. 14N should fit best.

Comment: @Andre Joost: Sorry, I am not familiar with _NAD…_. But EPSG notes that _area of use_ of _NAD83 (CSRS)_ is _Canada_. For _NAD 83_ it is _Canada and USA_. Are you sure that _NAD83 (CSRS)_ or _NAD 83_ is usable for the north east of Mexico?

Comment: The proj parametres are all the same.

Comment: OK, Andre Joost is right: _NAD 83_ is virtually the same as _WGS 84_. So user20159 can use _NAD 83 / UTM zone 14N_ or _NAD83 (CSRS) / UTM zone 14N_ or _WGS 84 / UTM zone 14N_.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to tell is to go to the area in Google Earth then go to Tools-->Options --> Show Lat/Long and select "Universal Transverse Mercator" and click apply.

At the bottom just to the left of the coords is the UTM zone, move your mouse to the area you are working on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link for you to download [UTM download](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/coordsys/grids/universal_grid_system.html) should you or anyone who reads here

Enjoy !